# Como Editar Registros de una Base de Datos SQL y guardar los cambios sin agregar un nuevo registro en Python y Tkinter?

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, visual-studio, tkinter

tengo una consulta, estoy desarrollando un proyecto de gestion, en la ventana de carga de clientes tengo un frame donde cargo los datos, en este frame tambien tengo definido un boton que abre una ventana nueva (toplevel con un treeview) y me muestra los clientes cargados en mi base de datos, al seleccionar un item  y darle al boton editar me muestra los datos en el frame principal, hasta aca todo bien, el problema es cuando quiero modificar algo, le doy al boton guardar y me genera un nuevo registro cambiando el dato modificado en el nuevo registro.
podrian orientarme como hacerlo? tengo que agregar una verificacion en el boton guardar para ver si el registro existe y en ese caso modificar, y de lo contrario agregar?
en la funcion agregar_registro comente una consulta para validar pero no funciona.
de antemano agradezco recomendaciones.

```
from tkinter import ttk 
from tkinter import *
import pymssql
from tkinter import messagebox

class Clientes(Frame):

def __init__(self, master = None):
     super().__init__(master, width = 1300, height = 500)  #1920*1080
     self.master = master
     self.master.title(" CLIENTES ")
     #self.configure(bg = "Red")
     self.pack()
     self.VentanaPrincipal()


def VentanaPrincipal(self):

    #self.Ventana_Clientes = Toplevel(width = 1500, height = 750)
    #self.Ventana_Clientes.title(" CLIENTES - BUGSOFT")

    
    frame = Frame(self.master, width = 900, height = 450, bg = "green")
    #frame = Frame(self.Ventana_Clientes, width = 900, height = 450)
    frame.place(x = 50, y = 60)
    #frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

    # Entrada de Numero de cuenta
    Label(frame, text = 'Cuenta: ').grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    self.cuenta = Entry(frame)
    self.cuenta.focus()
    self.cuenta.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
    
    # Entrada de Nombre
    Label(frame, text = 'Razon Social: ').grid(row = 2, column = 0)
    self.razon_social = Entry(frame)
    self.razon_social.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
    
    # Nombre Fantasia
    Label(frame, text = 'Nombre Comercial: ').grid(row = 2, column = 2)
    self.nombre_comercial = Entry(frame)
    self.nombre_comercial.grid(row = 2, column = 4)

    # Entrada de Direccion
    Label(frame, text = 'Direccion: ').grid(row = 3, column = 0)
    self.direccion = Entry(frame)
    self.direccion.grid(row = 3, column = 1)

    #Direccion local
    Label(frame, text = 'Direccion Comercial: ').grid(row = 3, column = 2)
    self.direccion_comercial = Entry(frame)
    self.direccion_comercial.grid(row = 3, column = 4)

    # Entrada Codigo Postal - los siguientes 4 campos(CP-loc-prov-pais) son en la misma linea
    Label(frame, text = 'Codigo Postal: ').grid(row = 4, column = 0)
    self.cp = Entry(frame)
    self.cp.grid(row = 4, column = 1)

    #Entrada localidad
    Label(frame, text = 'Localidad: ').grid(row = 4, column = 2)
    self.localidad = Entry(frame)
    self.localidad.grid(row = 4, column = 4)

    #Entrada de Provincia
    Label(frame, text = 'Provincia: ').grid(row = 4, column = 5)
    self.provincia = Entry(frame)
    self.provincia.grid(row = 4, column = 6)

    #Entrada de Pais
    Label(frame, text = 'Pais: ').grid(row = 4, column = 7)
    self.pais = Entry(frame)
    self.pais.grid(row = 4, column = 8)

    ### terminan los items de la misma linea    

    # Entrada de Zona
    Label(frame, text = 'Zona: ').grid(row = 5, column = 0)
    self.zona = Entry(frame)
    self.zona.grid(row = 5, column = 1)

    #Entrada de Telefono
    Label(frame, text = 'Telefono: ').grid(row = 6, column = 0)
    self.telefono = Entry(frame)
    self.telefono.grid(row = 6, column = 1)

    #Entrada Vendedor
    Label(frame, text = 'Vendedor: ').grid(row = 7, column = 0)
    self.vendedor = Entry(frame)
    self.vendedor.grid(row = 7, column = 1) 

    #Entrada Grupo
    Label(frame, text = 'Grupo: ').grid(row = 8, column = 0)
    self.grupo = Entry(frame)
    self.grupo.grid(row = 8, column = 1) 

    #Entrada Condicion de Venta
    Label(frame, text = 'Cond. Vta.: ').grid(row = 8, column = 2)
    self.CondicionVenta = Entry(frame)
    self.CondicionVenta.grid(row = 8, column = 4)

    #Entrada de Lista de Precio
    Label(frame, text = 'List. Pre.: ').grid(row = 8, column = 5)
    self.ListaPrecio = Entry(frame)
    self.ListaPrecio.grid(row = 8, column = 6)

    #Entrada de Credito de cuenta
    Label(frame, text = 'Cred. Cuenta: ').grid(row = 8, column = 7)
    self.CreditoCta = Entry(frame)
    self.CreditoCta.grid(row = 8, column = 8)
    
    #Entrada de Condicion frente a IVA 
    #cadena = self.run_query("SELECT Codigo_IVA FROM Clientes")
    cadena = ("IVA-Resp.Inscrip.", 
              "Monotri",
              "sin iva")        

    Label(frame, text = 'Codigo IVA: ').grid(row = 9, column = 0)
    self.CodIVA = ttk.Combobox(frame, values = cadena)
    self.CodIVA.grid(row = 9, column = 1)
    
    #Entrada Numero CUIT
    Label(frame, text = 'CUIT: ').grid(row = 9, column = 2)
    self.NumCUIT = Entry(frame)
    self.NumCUIT.grid(row = 9, column = 4)

    #Entrada de Numero de Ingresos Brutos
    Label(frame, text = 'Ing. Brutos: ').grid(row = 9, column = 5)
    self.NumIngBru = Entry(frame)
    self.NumIngBru.grid(row = 9, column = 6)

    #Entrada de Observaciones
    Label(frame, text = 'Observaciones: ').grid(row = 10, column = 0)
    self.observaciones = Entry(frame)
    self.observaciones.grid(row = 10, column = 1)

    
    # Boton Agregar Proveedor Ver Lista de Proveedores
    Button(frame, text = 'Guardar Proveedor', command = self.agregar_proveedor).grid(row = 17, column = 0)
    Button(frame, text = 'Ver Proveedores', command = self.ver_proveedores).grid(row = 17, column = 5)

    # Mensajes de Salida 

def run_query(self, query, parameters = ()):
    with pymssql.connect( host=r'10.1.1.100:54583\SQLEXPRESS', user=r'sa', password='admin', database='test') as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
        conn.commit()
    return result


# Validacion datos ingresados por usuario
def validation(self):
    return len(self.cuenta.get()) != 0 and len(self.razon_social.get()) != 0 and len(self.nombre_comercial.get()) != 0 and len(self.direccion.get()) != 0

def agregar_proveedor(self):

        # self.run_query("""UPDATE Clientes SET Cuenta = %s, 
        #                Nombre_Cliente = %s, Nombre_Comercial = %s, Direccion = %s, 
        #                Direccion_Comercial = %s, Codido_Postal = %s, Localidad = %s, 
        #                Provincia = %s, Pais = %s, Zona = %s, Telefono = %s, Vendedor = %s, Grupo = %s, 
        #                Condicion_Venta = %s, Lista_Precio = %s, Credito_Cuenta = %s, Codigo_IVA = %s, 
        #                CUIT = %s, Ingresos_Brutos = %s, Observaciones = %s WHERE Cuenta = %s, 
        #                Nombre_Cliente = %s, Nombre_Comercial = %s, Direccion = %s, 
        #                Direccion_Comercial = %s, Codido_Postal = %s, Localidad = %s, 
        #                Provincia = %s, Pais = %s, Zona = %s, Telefono = %s, Vendedor = %s, Grupo = %s, 
        #                Condicion_Venta = %s, Lista_Precio = %s, Credito_Cuenta = %s, Codigo_IVA = %s, 
        #                CUIT = %s, Ingresos_Brutos = %s, Observaciones = %s """)

    if self.validation():
        
        query = 'INSERT INTO Clientes VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'
        parameters =  (self.cuenta.get(), self.razon_social.get(), 
                       self.nombre_comercial.get(), self.direccion.get(), 
                       self.direccion_comercial.get(), self.cp.get(), 
                       self.localidad.get(), self.provincia.get(), 
                       self.pais.get(), self.zona.get(), self.telefono.get(), 
                       self.vendedor.get(), self.grupo.get(),self.CondicionVenta.get(), 
                       self.ListaPrecio.get(),self.CreditoCta.get(), self.CodIVA.get(), 
                       self.NumCUIT.get(), self.NumIngBru.get(), self.observaciones.get())
        self.run_query(query, parameters)
        messagebox.showinfo(title = "Guardar", message = f"El Cliente {self.nombre_comercial.get()} se ha Guardado Correctamente")
        self.cuenta.delete(0, END)
        self.razon_social.delete(0, END)
        self.nombre_comercial.delete(0, END)
        self.direccion.delete(0, END)
        self.direccion_comercial.delete(0, END)
        self.cp.delete(0, END)
        self.localidad.delete(0, END)
        self.provincia.delete(0, END)
        self.pais.delete(0, END)
        self.zona.delete(0, END)
        self.telefono.delete(0, END)
        self.vendedor.delete(0, END)
        self.grupo.delete(0, END)
        self.CondicionVenta.delete(0, END)
        self.ListaPrecio.delete(0, END)
        self.CreditoCta.delete(0, END)
        self.CodIVA.delete(0, END)
        self.NumCUIT.delete(0, END)
        self.NumIngBru.delete(0, END)
        self.observaciones.delete(0, END)
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo(title = "Guardar", message = "Algunos Campos no pueden estar vacios")
    self.cuenta.focus()


def ver_proveedores(self): 
    self.Ventana = Toplevel()
    self.Ventana.title ('Lista de Clientes') 
    self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.Ventana, height = 10, columns = ('#1','#2','#3'))
    ttk.Button(self.Ventana, text = 'Eliminar', command = self.eliminar_proveedor).grid(row = 5, column = 8, sticky = W + E)
    ttk.Button(self.Ventana, text = 'Editar', command = self.editar_proveedor).grid(row = 5, column = 5, sticky = W + E)
    self.tree.grid(row = 4, column = 5, columnspan = 4)
    self.tree.heading('#0', text = 'Nro. Cuenta', anchor = CENTER)
    self.tree.heading('#1', text = 'Nombre', anchor = CENTER)
    self.tree.heading('#2', text = 'Nombre Comercial', anchor = CENTER)
    self.tree.heading('#3', text = 'Domicilio', anchor = CENTER) 
    self.proveedores()
    # mensaje salida 
    self.texto = Label(self.Ventana, text = '', fg = 'red')
    self.texto.grid(row = 3, column = 5, columnspan = 5, sticky = W + E)

    # limpiar Tabla 
def proveedores(self):    
    registros = self.tree.get_children()
    for element in registros:
        self.tree.delete(element)
    # Seleccionar datos
    conn = pymssql.connect( host=r'10.1.1.100:54583\SQLEXPRESS', user=r'sa', password='admin', database='test') 
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""SELECT Cuenta, Nombre_Cliente, Nombre_Comercial, Direccion, Direccion_Comercial, 
                   Codido_Postal, Localidad, Provincia, Pais, Zona, Telefono, Vendedor, Grupo, 
                   Condicion_Venta, Lista_Precio, Credito_Cuenta, Codigo_IVA, CUIT, Ingresos_Brutos, Observaciones 
                   FROM Clientes ORDER BY Cuenta DESC""")
    for row in cursor:
        self.tree.insert('', 0, text = row[0], values = row[1:20]) 
    conn.close()

def eliminar_proveedor(self):
    try:
        self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][0]
    except IndexError as e:
        messagebox.showerror(title = "Error", message = " Debe Seleccionar un Registro ")
        return
    cuentaseleccionada = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['text']
    query = 'DELETE FROM Clientes WHERE Cuenta = %s '
    self.run_query(query, (cuentaseleccionada, ))
    messagebox.showinfo(title = " Eliminar ", message = f"Se ha Eliminado la Cuenta {(cuentaseleccionada)}")
    self.proveedores()
    
def editar_proveedor(self):
    
    try:
        self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][0]
    except IndexError:
        messagebox.showerror(title = "Error", message = " Debe Seleccionar un Registro ")
        return
    datos = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())
    cuenta = datos ['text']
    nombre = datos ['values'][0] 
    nomcom = datos ['values'][1]
    direcc = datos ['values'][2]
    dir_com = datos ['values'][3]
    cp = datos['values'][4]
    local = datos['values'][5] 
    prov = datos['values'][6]
    pais = datos['values'][7]
    zona = datos['values'][8]
    tel = datos['values'][9]
    vende = datos['values'][10]
    grupo = datos['values'][11]
    con_ven = datos['values'][12]
    lispre = datos['values'][13]
    crecta = datos['values'][14]
    iva = datos['values'][15]
    cuit = datos['values'][16]
    inbru = datos['values'][17]
    obs = datos['values'][18]

    self.cuenta.insert(0, cuenta) 
    self.razon_social.insert(0, nombre)
    self.nombre_comercial.insert(0, nomcom) 
    self.direccion.insert(0, direcc) 
    self.direccion_comercial.insert(0, dir_com) 
    self.cp.insert(0, cp)
    self.localidad.insert(0, local)
    self.provincia.insert(0, prov)
    self.pais.insert(0, pais)
    self.zona.insert(0, zona)
    self.telefono.insert(0, tel)
    self.vendedor.insert(0, vende)
    self.grupo.insert(0, grupo)
    self.CondicionVenta.insert(0, con_ven)
    self.ListaPrecio.insert(0, lispre)
    self.CreditoCta.insert(0, crecta)
    self.CodIVA.insert(0, iva)
    self.NumCUIT.insert(0, cuit)
    self.NumIngBru.insert(0, inbru)
    self.observaciones.insert(0, obs)

    self.Ventana.destroy()

     

if __name__ == '__main__':
root = Tk()
application = Clientes(root)
application.mainloop()
```

Comment: Tu pregunta es teorica... hay varias formas de hacer esto.. una simple seria obtener el id del registro, y tenerlo a mano, para que si ese id es distinto a (ponele cero) entonces haces un update...

Comment: Si, es teorica, aunque si pueden mostrar como quedaria seria una gran guia para terminar este modulo, a estas horas ya me cuesta mucho todo jaja como puedo obtener solamente el id del treeview? si al usar el metodo tree.item(tree.selection()) me devuelve la tupla con todos los datos del item

Comment: No se nada de python.. tu pregunta es teorica, no se como se hace en tu codigo... es mas.. puede haber otro tipo de formas totalmetne validas...

Comment: claro, intente hacer lo que planteaste pero no consigo almacenar ese dato unicamente del treeview, incluso en la pregunta lo plantee en forma de duda lo de la id. en Cobol lo hice alguna vez, en python lo estoy intentando ahora, seguire probando otros metodos, muchas gracias!

Comment: Cuando haces tree.item estás obteniendo un diccionario con los datos del item. Text es una opción distinta, por lo tanto, no estará en la tupla values. Tenés que hacer tree.item(...)["text"] para obtener el primer valor y ["values"] para obtener el resto de valores. Te aconsejaría otra forma de diseñar el treeview para evitar esa tecnica molesta, pero me desviaría demasiado de la pregunta original, por lo que no puedo publicarlo.

Comment: Hola Dante, estaba esperando tu respuesta, haciendo lo que decis me genera este error 
return self.tk.splitlist(self.tk.call(self._w, "selection"))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!toplevel.!treeview"

tengo dos variables: cuenta y db 
cuenta = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['text'][0]
db = self.run_query(f"SELECT Cuenta FROM Clientes WHERE Cuenta = '"+cuenta+"' ")
luego de esto declaro un if y si es correcto debe guardar, pero me da el error mencionado arriba

Answer (score 0):

##### Upsert: Insertar si no existe, de lo contrario modificar

Lo que querés lograr se llama upsert (proviente de update e insert).

Algunos (no todos, sql server no lo tiene) motores de bases de datos ofrecen una forma (dependiente del motor) de diseñar las consultas que permite hacer el upsert. En postgresql existe [ON CONFLICT](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-upsert/).

Pero como dije antes, sql server no lo tiene, por lo que hay que hacer un procedure en el lado del server o hacer parte del trabajo del lado del cliente.

La idea de esto ultimo es usar la función exists, que devuelve un booleano indicando si la consulta generó o no datos, siendo la consulta de la siguiente estructura.

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE ...)
```

Donde el where indica la condición que debe cumplirse para encontrar el proveedor.

Con el booleano, podés hacer un condicional de Python del estilo:

```
if existe:
    cursor.execute("UPDATE ...")
else:
    cursor.execute("INSERT ...")
```

##### Validación

Eso ya lo tenés bastante bien resuelto. Lo unico que agregaría es un mensaje por cada caso. Esto para que el usuario sepa que es lo que salió mal y no reciba un mensaje generico de "datos incorrectos".

##### Mencionando errores

Tu código tiene algunos errores:

- **insertas cada registro obtenido en la posición 0** Esto va a hacer que aparescan en la tabla en el orden inverso al que llegaron.
  Piensa que ese 0 indica "creá una fila antes de la fila 0". En su lugar, usá la cadena `end`, que dice que se ubique al final.
- **Que devuelve realmente treeview.selection()** En realidad, nos devuelve una tupla con los ids de los items seleccionados. Muchas veces, usas directamente este resultado en treeview.items, pero eso recibe una sola id. Si queremos ver que haya exactamente un solo elemento seleccionado, basta con `len(self.tree.selection()) == 1`, y para obtener el id del item seleccionado, hacer `self.tree.selection()[0]` (obtenemos el primer elemento de la tupla) luego de tener la certeza de que hay al menos un elemento seleccionado. Y recién ahí, podemos usar eso en treeview.items.
- Adicionalmente, es posible restringir al usuario a que pueda seleccionar un solo elemento configurando al treeview (durante su creación o usando el método config). Esta opción magica sería `selectmode="browse"`. Otros valores posibles son none (no se puede seleccionar nada) y extended (default).
- **treeview.item(...)['values'] no suele ser vacío** values contiene los valores de la fila. Y, aunque una celda esté vacía, tiene un valor (una cadena vacía). Esto lo aclaro ya que es usado en un try...except que captura un IndexError.
- **Al abrir un messagebox, se enfocará la ventana raiz** Al igual que los Toplevels, los messagebox tienen una ventana padre. Esta ventana por default es la raiz (la generada con Tk()) y al abrirse enfocarán dicha ventana. Para que enfoque la ventana esperada, hay que aclararlo explicitamente pasando a todos los messagebox el argumento `parent=toplevel`. También se puede hacer `parent=self` si self representa a la ventana padre o uno de sus widgets.
- **El contenido de los campos siempre es una cadena** Aunque podría no dar un error, vale la pena aclararlo. Tkinter no tiene modo de saber, tal y como está diseñado, si el campo es numerico, de texto, fecha, etc. Lo que significa que siempre recibirás como cadena los valores de los campos. Lo mismo pasa con los treeviews. Es posible que el motor de base de datos convierta implicitamente las cadenas en los tipos de datos correspondientes (eso hace postgresql). Aún así, tenlo en cuenta a la hora de trabajar con el ingreso del usuario.

#### Consejos

- **self.master ya existe** y representa el padre del widget. Por lo que "crear" este atributo no solo es redundante, si no que si decides hacer algún cambio en su valor, podrías romper el funcionamiento de tkinter.
- **show="headings"** Si pasas esto como argumento durante la creación del treeview, la molesta columna default (con la que accedes usando `["text"]`) ya no va a aparecer más y podrás seguir escribiendo tu código como si esa columna no existiese. Ahora, la primera columna no será la default.
- **Campos en blanco y otros bugs de la validación** Es posible que el usuario ingrese espacios en blanco en los campos de texto. En programación, un espacio es considerado un caracter, a diferencia de la escritura informal. Eso significa que `len("  ")` no va a ser igual a 0 y te dará verdadero, y, al ser una cadena valida, Python no te mandará ningún error.
- También es posible que ingrese un número no valido en un campo númerico (como una letra, o incluso un signo). Este escenario, si no lo evitas de algún modo, producirá un error en la consulta u otras partes de tu programa.
- **Preguntado** La baja es un proceso arriesgado. En tu programa, si un usuario presiona el botón de baja sin querer, va a borrar un proveedor entero. Lo habitual, es preguntar al usuario si está seguro de eliminar para reducir esa posibilidad.
- **StringVar** Los stringvars son buena opción para usar junto a los campos. Al stringvar se le puede establecer el valor sin el molesto `campo.delete(0, "end");campo.insert(0, ...)`. Otra ventaja es que, mientras campo.delete y campo.insert no funcionan cuando el entry está bloqueado, el stringvar si funciona.